# How to get the html of a div on another page with jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery's ajax code to load new pages, but wanted him to get only the html of a div.

My codes:
HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
$.ajax({
   url:href,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(data){
       $('#content').html(data);
   }
});
```

I wanted him to get only the html of $('div#content') on another page. How to do it?

Answer (score 52):

Ok, You should "construct" the html and find the .content div.

like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url:href,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(data){
       $('#content').html($(data).find('#content').html());
   }
});
```

Simple!

Comment: Don't do this, doing this will cause scripts to run from the other page potentially - it's a weird issue that may not affect you but I recommend using .load which will strip the scripts. Ala

`var loadHolder = $('<div></div>');

  loadHolder.load(href + ' #content', function(){
    $('#content').loadHolder.find('#content').html())
  })`

Comment: can this be done with javascript `fetch` ?

Comment: I tried to do this and my HTML page being fetched is same as above, but `$(data).find('#content')` but this `$(data)[47].innerHTML` does. I have a `div` with `id="content"` in the page being fetched. Any clue ?

Answer (score 34):

You can use JQuery .load() method:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
 $( "#content" ).load( "ajax/test.html div#content" );
```

Comment: Perfect! Any idea how to get it to load images correctly that are given a root link `/` instead of relative `../` or absolute `http://example.com/`? Basically, how can you get it to load the images into another site?

Comment: @fredsbend You can't do cross-site loading, so you must use relative links. The best you can do is with a JavaScript bookmarklet.

Answer (score 18):

If you are looking for content from different domain this will do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.corsproxy.com/' +
        'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briarcliff_Manor,_New_York',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
           $('#content').html($(data).find('#firstHeading').html());
        }
});
```

Comment: hey it's Briarcliff!! :D I'm from White Plains

Comment: doing this will cause scripts to run from the other page potentially - its a weird issue that may not affect you but I recommend using .load

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately an ajax request gets the entire file, but you can filter the content once it's retrieved:

```
$.ajax({
   url:href,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(data) {
       var content = $('<div>').append(data).find('#content');
       $('#content').html( content );
   }
});
```

Note the use of a dummy element as `find()` only works with descendants, and won't find root elements.

or let jQuery filter it for you:

```
$('#content').load(href + ' #IDofDivToFind');
```

I'm assuming this isn't a cross domain request, as that won't work, only pages on the same domain.

Comment: I've been trying to do something similar for hours and just reading your reply "Note the use of a dummy element as find() only works with descendants, and won't find root elements." helped me immensely. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
  url:href,
  type:'get',
  success: function(data){
   console.log($(data)); 
  }
});
```

This console log gets an array like object: [meta, title, ,], very strange

You can use JavaScript：

```
var doc = document.documentElement.cloneNode()
doc.innerHTML = data
$content = $(doc.querySelector('#content'))
```