# How to link from one html and display single div of many divs present in second html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to create

A.html : It contains links (Topic Headings)

B.html : It contains description of various topics separated in DIV's  in a single html file

The size of B.html is very large...So when i link A.html with div id of B.html it loads entire B.html

Is there any way i can link both A and B so that link on A displays only linked DIV of B as a popup or in new tab...

This is code approach i was using

```
A.html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<a href="B.html#div1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"/>Link to Topic in Page B</a>
</div>
</body>

B.html
<html>
<body>
<div id="div1">
Description of Topic A
</div>
<div id="div2">
Description of Topic B
</div>
<div id="div3">
Description of Topic C
</div>
<div id="div4">
Description of Topic D
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show your code effort.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938180/how-to-get-the-html-of-a-div-on-another-page-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: I know html/css/javascript only....if this requires more than it...please suggest topic only so that i can understand it before changing my approach

Answer (score 0):

Open part of the B.html in a separate tab or display it from the A.html is possible with the iframe tag, but if you want to display specific div, I think you need to use a javascript: see [Load content of a div on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101770/load-content-of-a-div-on-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

Hope below solution might help you

```
<span class="TopicHeadings" linkPageName="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_whoiswho.htm #ab">Topic Heading 1</span><br>
<span class="TopicHeadings" linkPageName="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_whoiswho.htm #Aa">Topic Heading 2</span><br>
<span class="TopicHeadings" linkPageName="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_whoiswho.htm #bs">Topic Heading 3</span><br>
<div id="divContent"></div>




$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".TopicHeadings").on( "click", function() {
       var linkPageName = $(this).attr("linkPageName");
       $('#divContent').load(linkPageName, function() {
          alert( "Load was performed." );
       });
    });
 });
```

Fiddler link : [sample code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/97qoL1yo/3/)

Comment: You can go with below definition,

Comment: Separating divs into html pages might be difficult as large number of divs will mean large no of pages to upkeep.