# Ajax .load retrieves what from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It is a simple doubt:
When we use something like `$('#content').load( "page.php #content");`, it loads the entire `page.php` "in server-side" and then extract `#content` element or it loads only the specified element?

Beyond that, is this `$('#content').load( "page.php #content");` the same as this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"page.php",
    type:'GET',
    error: function(){
        alert("Oops!"); // Em caso de o AJAX dar erro (opcional)
    },
    success:
    function(data){
        $('#content').html($(data).find('#content').html());
    }
});
```

When it comes to "method to get from the server"?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938180/how-to-get-the-html-of-a-div-on-another-page-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with that question. My doubt wasn't about how to do something, but how does something works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those would be the same, XMLHttpRequest can not load partial pages.
jQuery splits the url and the given selector, and then loads the entire page based on the url, and then just extracts the given element(s) based on the passed in selector as a filter using `find()`.

Here's a shortened (somewhat modified) version of jQuery's `load()`, just to show how it works

```
function(url, params, callback) {
    var selector, div, html, self = this;

    // if the url param contains a space, get the selector to use as filter
    if ( url.indexOf(" ") > -1 ) { 
        selector = jQuery.trim(url.slice( url.indexOf(" ") ));
        url = url.slice(0, url.indexOf(" "));
    }

    // make regular ajax call
    jQuery.ajax({
        url      : url,
        type     : "GET",
        dataType : "html",
        data     : params
    }).done(function(responseText) {
        div  = jQuery('<div>');
        html = jQuery.parseHTML(responseText);

        self.html(  div.append( html ).find(selector) );
    });

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `#` and everything after it is never passed to the server.

Comment: Thank you, that is the explanation I was looking for :)