# Display single element of another webpage in my webpage

Tags: html, dynamic, element, scrape

So far, Google has only provided how to display an entire webpage within another webpage - I know how to do that.  However, I need to display a particular element value from another webpage in my own.  I can't find any info on how to do that sort of thing within an html page.  I know how to do webscraping via vbscript, but that involves a .vbs file and scraping Internet Explorer.  I don't think that method applies here.  I need to be able to dynamically pull and display another pages text within my page.

For example, to simply display the Google Search button text "Google Search" in a page, I tried (I know this is wrong, but just as an example...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

<script language="VBScript">

Function getText()

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = true
IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"
Do While IE.Busy or IE.ReadyState <> 4:Loop

For each a in ie.getElementsByTagName("input")
    if a.name = "btnk" then 
        content.innerhtml = a.value 
    end if
next

End function
</script>

    <body>      
        <div>
            <a onclick="getText()" href="#">Click Me</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Webpage text element will display here...
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Any idea how I might be able to achieve this?

EDIT** 2nd Attempt (not working):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>

<script>
Function getText()
$( "#content" ).load( "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl input#btnk" );

</script>
    <body>      
        <div>
            <a onclick="getText()" href="#">Click Me</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Webpage text element will display here...
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: use jquery to both retrieve the data into a variable and to select the specific element on the page.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938180/how-to-get-the-html-of-a-div-on-another-page-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: Awesome!  This looks to be what I need.  I'll explore it.

Comment: Not sure I'm implementing it correctly.  Can you tell where I'm going wrong?: https://pastebin.com/VvUQwr0V

Comment: Update your question with your code.

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice pastebin link, but question updated with latest code attempt.

Comment: @stephen.vakil updated code posted above