# access a Url with a query inside a modal

Tags: javascript, html, django, modal-dialog

I want to open the content of a page inside a modal, but this page is accessed by a query string like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8003/dados/add_dados?filter=crew
```

So, my modal needs to access the page, but I can't include a url, just a html page:

```
<button id="myBtn">+ Add</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
     {% block survey_index %}

      {% include 'add_data?filter=crew' %} #It doesn't work

     {% end block %}
    </div>
</div>
```

This way doesn't work since the include expects me to pass a html page like:

```
{% block sample_unit_type_index %}

    {% include 'inv/index/example.html' %}

{% endblock %}
```

How to access the page that is in add_data?filter=crew

url code:

```
path('add_data', add_data, name="add_data"),
```

views.py return

```
return render(request, 'inv/add_new.html', context)
```

So the page add_new.html has the content accessed by the queries. Example:

```
<a href="add_dados?filter={{path_info}}" class="btn3 add" role="button">Add</a>
```

Any suggests to access the add_data?filter=crew page content in modal?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to include the HTML template `add_new.html` then you can use:

```
{% block survey_index %}
      {% include 'inv/add_new.html' %}
{% end block %}
```

If you want to get the HTML from the URL then you can use an AJAX call as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938468/15353043):

HTML:

```
<button id="myBtn">+ Add</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div id="modal-content"></div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"{% url 'add_data' %}?filter=crew">,
       type:'GET',
       success: function(data){
           $('#modal-content').html(data);
       }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: it almost worked, but I can't access it with the query, just the url alone. for example: url:"{% url 'index' %}". But if I put a query in the url it still doesn't work. I think the syntax is wrong and I can't figure out what it looks like.

url:"{% url 'add_dados' %}?filter=crew" --> doesn't work

Comment: In url.py the url name is 'add_data'. So please check if it should be 'add_dados' or 'add_data' in every file. You can also include `error: function(data){console.log(data);` to your ajax call to check if there is an error.